# How do I visit a constant term in antlr4 with c++?

Tags: c++, parsing, antlr4, visitor-pattern

I have a grammar that at some point has the following rule:

```
boolConst : 
        'true'
      | 'false';
```

This leads to the following code (with visitor activated) being generated:

```
  class  BoolConstContext : public antlr4::ParserRuleContext {
  public:
     BoolConstContext(antlr4::ParserRuleContext *parent, size_t invokingState);
     virtual size_t getRuleIndex() const override;
     antlr4::tree::TerminalNode *TRUE();
     antlr4::tree::TerminalNode *FALSE();

     virtual std::any accept(antlr4::tree::ParseTreeVisitor *visitor) override;

  };
```

If I understand this correctly I cannot use the visitor to decent into the tree further, or at least I cannot find a `visitTRUE` or `visitFALSE` function in the `BaseVisitor` class.

Now when implementing a visitor based on the `BaseVisitor` I have to implement the function `virtual std::any visitBoolConst(BoolConstContext *ctx) override`.

However, I now need to know which of the two were parsed, whether it was FALSE, or TRUE
So I am wondering if doing something like the following is correct and what should be done.

```
    if (ctx->FALSE() != nullptr) {
        // false was parsed
    } else if (ctx->TRUE() != nullptr) {
        // true was parsed
    } else {
        throw std::exception();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to use named alternatives:

```
boolConst : 
        'true' # boolConstTrue
      | 'false' # boolConstFalse;
```

ANTLR will generate different Context classes for each alternative (`BoolConstTrueContext` and `BoolConstFalseContext`).  Then the value would be implicit in the type.